# 64 Bit C compiler for Windows 7

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I am having 64 bit Windows 7 as my operating system and want to run some c programs. Is there a compiler for the same? I mean a 64 bit c compiler.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can try [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/).  It's a 64-bit distribution of GCC for Windows.  I think you want [mingw-w64-1.0-bin_i686-mingw_20100702.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/mingw-w64-1.0-bin_i686-mingw_20100702.zip/download).  This distribution is actively maintained, and GCC has quite good support for modern C.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I have downloaded the zip file extracted it but m not able to figure it out how to install it. Can u help me here.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I am having the same problem. When I go to the web site http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-release/ and browse to the "Home / mingw-w64 / mingw-w64-release" directory, all I see is the .gz and .bz2 files. Which of these should I pick for the windows platform? Is there a .zip or .exe file for this compiler?

Comment: @Ayusman,  mingw-w64-v2.0.6.tar.gz should work.  You can open the .gz with http://www.7-zip.org/ .  If that doesn't work, you can install Cygwin and choose mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core.  See mention of this at http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/ (it gives the right path).

Answer (score 4):

You could use the C compiler provided with Visual Studio 2010 (or probably 2008), just set your target type to x64 and compile .c files, you will get a 64-bit EXE.

Comment: It's important to note that `cl` does not support the latest C standard (C99), and Microsoft [has said](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/485416/support-c99) they are not planning to fix this.

Comment: MSVC support for C is **dreadful**. It's so bad I prefer C++ over C on Windows.

Comment: On the bright side, I think on the whole ANSI C89 is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a development environment as well, Visual C++ (Express) might be worth a peek:  http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/

Comment: I don't think Express does 64-bits.

Comment: Really? According to MSDN, you can configure Express to do compile to x64...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx